# Verificar se existe chave no array/json

Tags: php

Bom tenho o seguinte json:

```
{
"Autenticacao": [{
    "login": "teste",
    "token": "100",
    "senha": "123"
}]
}
```

Recebo esse Json assim:

```
// Recebe JSON
$json = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'json', FILTER_DEFAULT);

// Decodifica json
$jsonObj = json_decode($json);
```

Como verifica se o json tem a chave `Autenticacao`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode usar a função [`array_key_exist`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-key-exists.php) mas para isso você precisar informar ao `json_decode` para converter o `json` para `array` e não `objeto`, ou utilizar a função [`property_exists`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.property-exists.php) para testar o `objeto`.

**Verificar com `objeto`:**

```
$raw = '{"Autenticacao": [{"login": "teste","token": "100","senha": "123"}]}';

$jsonData = json_decode($raw); 
// Segundo parametro define que a conversão sera para array

var_dump(property_exists($jsonData, 'Autenticacao'));
// Saida: true
```

**Verificar com conversão para `array`:**

```
$raw = '{"Autenticacao": [{"login": "teste","token": "100","senha": "123"}]}';

$jsonData = json_decode($raw, true); 
// Segundo parametro define que a conversão sera para array

var_dump(array_key_exists('Autenticacao', $jsonData));
// Saida: true
```

**Validação de dados vindo do `POST`**

De acordo com a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php#refsect1-function.filter-input-returnvalues), a função `filter_input` tera o seguinte retorno;

> **Valor Retornado**
>
> Valor da requisitada variável em caso de sucesso, FALSE se o filtro falhar, ou NULL se o parâmetro variable_name é um variável não definida. Se a flag FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE é usada, ela retorna FALSE se a variável não é definida e NULL se o filtro falhar.

Sabendo disse a validação pode ser feita apenas com um `if`

```
// $json = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'json', FILTER_DEFAULT);
// o filtro FILTER_DEFAULT já é aplicado por padrão então ele pode ser removido
$json = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'json', FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
// A variavel $json contera o valor da variavel ou NULL/FALSE em caso de erro.

if ($json) { ...
```

Comment: Deu certo, porém estou tendo esse erros `Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in` ele ocorre na linha `array_key_exists('Autenticacao', $jsonData)`. Notei que ele ocorre quando o `INPUT_POST` esta vazio, tenho que verificar se eu recebi um Json, sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: vou adicionar essa informação @HugoBorges

Comment: @HugoBorges adicionei as informações.

Comment: Ok deu certo aqui, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você faz um `$jsonObj = json_decode($json)` o PHP já transforma o $json em array, daí você pode fazer um teste lógico simples, como `if(isset($jsonObj['Autenticacao']))`

Comment: Errado. A função `json_decode` converte o JSON para um objeto, instância da `stdClass`, por padrão. Para converter para um *array* associativo o segundo parâmetro da função deve ser `true`: `json_decode($json, true)`.